# Repast Simphony: runtime NullPointerException caused by the network projection

Tags: java, repast-simphony

I'm having troubles with Repast Simphony with the network projection. I have a series of agents arranged in a ring, on a ContinuousSpace, and each agent is connected to its successor using a network projection. In practive, every agent has an Edge starting in itself and pointing to its successor, and in turn it is pointed by another Edge.
Agents come and go, and when executing the simulator I have the following stacktrace:

```
repast.simphony.ui.GUIScheduleRunner - RunTimeException when running the schedule
Current tick (20.0)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at saf.v3d.scene.VEdge2D.update(VEdge2D.java:90)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.NetworkLayerOGL2D.update(NetworkLayerOGL2D.java:96)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.DisplayOGL2D.update(DisplayOGL2D.java:410)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayComponentControllerAction$DisplayUpdater.execute(DisplayComponentControllerAction.java:48)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.DefaultAction.execute(DefaultAction.java:38)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.ScheduleGroup.executeList(ScheduleGroup.java:205)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.ScheduleGroup.execute(ScheduleGroup.java:238)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.Schedule.execute(Schedule.java:352)
    at repast.simphony.ui.GUIScheduleRunner$ScheduleLoopRunnable.run(GUIScheduleRunner.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Fun fact: if I remove the network projection from the display, nothing never fails.

Here is how I initialize the network and the continuous space in the builder:

```
NetworkBuilder<Object> netBuilder = new NetworkBuilder<Object>(
                "chord network", context, true);
        netBuilder.buildNetwork();

        ContinuousSpaceFactory spaceFactory = ContinuousSpaceFactoryFinder
                .createContinuousSpaceFactory(null);
        ContinuousSpace<Object> space = spaceFactory.createContinuousSpace(
                "space", context, new RandomCartesianAdder<Object>(),
                new repast.simphony.space.continuous.WrapAroundBorders(), 50,
                50);
```

In the code I access the network in this way

```
Network<Object> net = (Network<Object>)context.getProjection("chord network");
```

and finally, in the code of the agents, I change the edges in this way:

```
// removing the edge
if (this.edge != null)
    net.removeEdge(this.edge);

// adding a new edge
net.addEdge(this, this.successor);
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

EDIT:
What I'm simulating is Chord, a distributed hash table protocol. My agents are called *Nodes* and each node has a pointer to its predecessor and successor, and also it handles the edge that points itself to its successor.

At any tick, 3 random nodes are chosen and removed. This removal is intended as a voluntary leaving of the nodes, so every node notifies its successor and predecessor about the leave, in this way:

```
if (this.edge != null)
        this.net.removeEdge(this.edge);
this.successor.predecessor = this.predecessor;
if (this.predecessor != null) {
    this.predecessor.successor = this.successor;
    this.predecessor.successors = this.successors;
    if (this.predecessor.edge != null)
        this.net.removeEdge(this.predecessor.edge);
    this.predecessor.edge = this.net.addEdge(this.predecessor, this.successor);
}
```

After that, each removed node is removed from the context.

In a similar way, at every tick 3 new nodes are created. After choosing a random position, the node is added to the context, and an edge from itself pointing to its successor is added, in this way

```
// this.edge is an attribute of Node, that is a pointer to the network
this.edge = this.net.addEdge(this, this.successor);
```

Finally, every node has a series of scheduled methods, that are executed at every iteration. They check whether there is a new successor, and in such a case the current edge is removed, and a new edge is added

```
// in case a new successor is identified
if (this.edge != null)
    this.net.removeEdge(this.edge);
this.edge = this.net.addEdge(this, this.successor);
```

These are all the operations performed on the network. Of course the protocol is simulated at steady state, so at the beginning the builder creates a context with *N* nodes and all the corrected edges.

The moment when the error happens is non deterministic: sometimes after 150 ticks, some other times at the 5th.

Comment: Can you update your question with more information about how the network related parts of your simulation proceed. In particular the order of the operations -- agent added, edge added, agent deleted etc. with respect to each tick. It is hard to see how this NPE is triggered but hopefully that info will help.

Comment: @NickCollier I've just updated my question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it possible to get either your project or one that reproduces this behavior? I think there might be a bug in the display code that this network manipulation pattern is exposing. You can contact me on the repast mailing list if you don't want to share a link to your code here. Thanks.

Comment: @NickCollier you can find a zip with my code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALescbODYSQNMFHC9usChDzoQi5ZhuUZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Got it. I'll hopefully get a chance to look at it in the next few days.